# When installing julia and vscode. Get error 'Could not start the julia language server.'

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, vscode-extensions

First it worked. I cound uses the REPL inside vscode. Then the computer crashed when I tried to install julia package Plots, using REPL insode vscode. After that I have had an error no matter what I did with julia.executablePath. I have tried everything, including total reinstallation of both vscode and julia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Julia crashes when installing packages than often the package repo becomes corrupt.

The package repo is usually located  at the `.julia` folder in your `HOME` directory (unless `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` system variable points to a different location). Delete the `.julia` folder completely and restart Julia.

Comment: This implies reinstalling all packages and compile everything again.
Isn't there any less dramatic solution?

Comment: perhaps you might try to delete the packages from `.julia/compiled` and try editing `*.toml` files in the `.julia/environments` folder. I always preferred to reinstall from scratch